# How do I keep a Google Map marker in the center of the map without lag?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to keep a marker in the center of the map when a user drags the camera.

I'm currently doing this by using an OnCameraChangeListener like so:

```
@Override
public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
    marker.setPosition(map.getCameraPosition().target);
}
```

My problem with this is lag. The marker flickers and doesn't stay in place perfectly until I stop dragging.

I'm assuming a better way of doing this is to add some sort of overlay over-top the map.

Any suggestions?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557575/move-the-map-by-keeping-the-marker-in-center & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27455688/android-google-maps-v2-keep-marker-in-the-center-of-map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You are better of putting your `MapFragment` or `MapView` inside `FrameLayout` (or `RelativeLayout`) with another `ImageView` or anything else and setting its `gravity` to `center`.