# Move the Map by Keeping the marker in center

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

Whenever I move the map,Marker is also moving with that But I want to move the map by keeping the marker at the center of Map as constant.

How can i acheive this?

Comment: Is it like the map is following the marker in the center of the view like most navigation map apps; for example, Waze?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you add your marker as a view. overlay it on top of the map.

```
<RelaiveLayout  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<mapView ...  />
<ImageView  android:center_in_parent="true" ... android:src="@drawable/urmarker" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

or if your using a MapFragment  add the marker to the fragment activity

Answer (score -1):

```
    CameraPosition cameraPos = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(currentLAT), Double.parseDouble(currentLNG)))
                .zoom(10).bearing(0).tilt(0).build();
        mapView.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPos), null);
```

Set this way:

Comment: My question is, I dont want to move the marker, I want to move the map towards the marker at the center. At any point of time, marker should not be moved.