# Android Google Maps v2 - Keep marker in the center of map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, marker

I'm a new Android developer working with Google Maps v2 right now.

I just need to let the user drag the map but the initial marker shouldn't move with it.

This is my **layout**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtDirection"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_buscar"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_buscar" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my **MapActivity.java**, which displays the map:

```
public class MapaActivity extends Activity {

    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapa);

        if (map == null) {
            map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-12.0000, -77.0000)).title("Origin"));

        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(-12.0000, -77.0000), 14));

        }

    }

}
```

Is there any method of Google Maps that I can use?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557575/move-the-map-by-keeping-the-marker-in-center & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783087/how-do-i-keep-a-google-map-marker-in-the-center-of-the-map-without-lag

Answer (score 3):

You can simulate it.  Instead of using a real `Marker`, center an `ImageView` on top of the `MapView` in a `RelativeLayout`.